# Problem with ldap_bind depend on username

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have a problem with a script to log in in a php app with my windows domain.

```
// config
$ldapserver = 'domain IP';
$ldapuser      = 'user';  
$ldappass     = 'pass';
$ldaptree    = "OU=OU,DC=DC,DC=DC";

// connect 
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if($ldapconn) {
    // binding to ldap server
    
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);
    
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass) or die ("Error trying to bind: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        
        $username = 'domain\fernan';
        $user_pass = 'pass';
        
        ldap_bind($ldapconn, $username, $user_pass);
        
    }
}
```

Well. The problem in this case depends on the username. It's crazy but for now only fails with users that starts with F. I know, it seems impossible, but I don't know what can I do.

I tried to create differents users in the ldap server but only users that starts with F are failing.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've used double quotes in your test data, the `\f` character represents a form feed character. You'd probably have the same failure with `"domain\nick"`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

use either

```
"domain\\fernan"
```

or

```
'domain\fernan'
```

This would be the same conflict if you used `\n` for a new line character.

Comment: I tried this and doesn't fix it. I don't understand nothing :-(

Comment: Then I don't see anything else wrong with the code sorry.